# Reference request for calculus and integration on Banach spaces

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm looking for some references about calculus and integration on Banach spaces. In particular, I'm interested in some basic results about:

1. Derivatives and differentiation of continuous functions $f:I \rightarrow X$, where $I$  is a open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is a Banach space on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Integration of functions $f:I \rightarrow X$.
3. Complex differentiation of functions $f:\Omega \rightarrow X$, where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ is a Banach space on $\mathbb{C}$ (simple results about holomorphic functions which takes values in a Banach space).

My background includes calculus and integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$, measure theory, basic complex analysis, and basic results about Banach spaces (Hahn-Banach theorem, open mapping theorem, closed graph theorem).

Could someone suggest me some book or lecture notes where I can briefly recover some information about the topics I listed?

Comment: The book I described in my answer to [Reference Request: Differentials of Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3565719/13130) might be suitable for *some* of what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 1 on Riemann integration in [these notes](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/notes/pmath450.pdf) covers the integration of functions part of your question